# How can I find the current value for AUTOCOMMIT in my redshift / SQL Workbench connection?

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

I would like to "investigate" a bit the behavior of the Redshift AutoCommit setting through SQL Workbench / JDBC connection.

I can choose the setting on the connection page, or impose it through "SET AUTOCOMMIT ON/OFF"

But how can I find its current value within my connection?

The documentation for the [SET](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SET.html?shortFooter=true) command does not give much...

and [SHOW ALL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SHOW.html?shortFooter=true) does not mention this parameter...

Comment: Is this helpful? `Connection.setAutoCommit()`

Comment: I suppose this is javascript?
I was more meaning through a SQL Statement.
@botchniaque answered (SHOW AUTOCOMMIT)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `psql` client for connecting to Redshift.When I try to `SET` autocommit to `OFF` I'm getting an error saying `ERROR:  SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported`, which sounds like you cannot perform any operation in Redshift without a transaction, though I did not find any documentation about it.

```
psql \
--host=localhost \
--username=xxx \
--port=6506 \
--dbname=datalake
psql (10.5 (Ubuntu 10.5-0ubuntu0.18.04), server 8.0.2)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

datalake=# SHOW AUTOCOMMIT;
 autocommit 
------------
 on
(1 row)

datalake=# SET AUTOCOMMIT=false;
ERROR:  SET AUTOCOMMIT TO OFF is no longer supported
```

Comment: Thank You. I thought I had tried it but I obviously did not! :-(

Comment: @Eric Mamet, if you think my answer was helpful you can consider upvoting it :)

Comment: I actually did but it's not taken into account(yet?) because I am new to stack overflow...

Answer (score 0):

There is no "SQL" command that can do that in SQL Workbench/J

The only way you can currently see it, it by looking at the menu item. If the Autocommit item is selected, then it's turned on.

Alternatively you can look at the `Commit` or `Rollback` menu items. If they are disabled, then autocommit is turned on as well.